# Java - A value resets to 0 unexpectedly

Tags: java, loops

I'm making a derivative calculator that asks the user for the degree of their polynomial and then the coefficients for each term, partly because I'm an inexperienced programmer and can't parse input like `3x^4/4 + sin(x)`.

Here's my class.

```
package beta;

import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DerivativeCalculator 
{
    public DerivativeCalculator(String d, String v)
    {
        int degree = Integer.parseInt(d);

        double value = Double.parseDouble(v);

        coeffList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
        {
            String console = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the coefficient of the "
                    + "x^" + i + " term.");
            Double coeff = Double.parseDouble(console);

            coeffList.add(coeff);
        }

    }
    public double calc()
    {
        double dx = 0.0001;

        double x1 = value;
        double y1 = 0;
        for (int d = degree; d >= 0; d--)
        {
            y1 += coeffList.get(d) * Math.pow(x1, d);
        }

        double x2 = x1 + dx;
        double y2 = 0;
        for (int d = degree; d >= 0; d--)
        {
            y2 += coeffList.get(d) * Math.pow(x2, d);
        }

        double slope = (y2 - y1)/ (x2 - x1);

        DecimalFormat round = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
        round.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

        return Double.valueOf(round.format(slope));
    }

    public String getEquation()
    {
        String equation = "";
        for (int d = degree; d >= 0; d--)
        {
            equation = equation + String.valueOf(coeffList.get(d)) + "x^" + String.valueOf(d) + " + ";
        }
        return equation;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    private int degree;
    private double value;
    private List<Double> coeffList;

}
```

Now here's my test class.

```
package beta;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DerivativeCalculatorTest extends JApplet
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        String d = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the degree of your polynomial: ");
        String v = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the x value "
                + "at which you want to take the derivative");

        DerivativeCalculator myDerivCalc = new DerivativeCalculator(d, v);
        g2.drawString(String.valueOf(myDerivCalc.calc()), 10, 100);
        g2.drawString(myDerivCalc.getEquation(), 10, 40);
        g2.drawString(myDerivCalc.getValue(), 10, 70);
    }

}
```

Running this creates an applet window that displays

```
5.0x^0+
0.0
0.0
```

which is not the correct derivative.

I debugged my program and everything runs as expected until the view switches to my test class and it executes `g2.drawString(String.valueOf(myDerivCalc.calc()), 10, 100);`

After it executes this line, `degree` (the degree of the polynomial) resets to 0 even though the user entered 5. This then messes up all the for loops in my class.

Why does this happen? Any suggestions on fixing this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You redefine `degree` and `value` as **local** variables inside your constructor. They [**shadow**](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15) your class variables with the same name.

Do not re-declare them.

Instead of

```
  int degree = <something>;
  double value = <something>;
```

you need

```
  degree = <something>;
  value = <something>;
```

Comment: I would add that placing the attributes at the very end of the class is a terrible idea. They should be just before the first constructor of the class

Comment: Yes I was wondering why my variable names weren't turning blue colored as Eclipse usually formats them

Answer (score 3):

Isn't 5.0x^0 = 5.0 * 1 = 5.0, and the derivative of that is 0.. 
I believe your code is working.

Comment: When you post comments as answers you expose yourself to downvoting. When that happens you lose rep and become further away from being able to comment.

Comment: The equation I inputted was something like x^4-3x^3+x^2+2x^1+5x^0 but my program only displayed 5.0x^0. It completely ignored the rest of my polynomial

Comment: So until I attain 125 rep I can't help unless I know the exact answer? Ill delete this comment in a bit.

Comment: I think this is a valid answer. `5.0 x^0` is indeed a constant function. I'm just unsure about what is the `+` trailing character in the OP's snippet

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils What else would he do... its a perfectly reasonable thing to post...

Comment: @Dici yes, I mentioned that in a comment before. The extra `+` is due to my getEquation() class. I will fix that later.

Comment: @3kings, I didn't make the rules. When you have little rep, unless you're posting an answer, you're sort of muted. They said - "posting here because not enough rep for comments" so they don't think it's an answer.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils If it attempts to answer the question, it's an answer. This attempts to answer the question, even in the original revision.

Comment: @Undo, well I'm not going to argue with a mod but you must have realized the original version is phrased as two questions and a disclaimer that it's not an answer. If they said it was a comment I don't see how anyone can say it wasn't.